# Gin-Gonic Content-Type restriction

Tags: go, mime-types, content-type, go-gin

There is a service written in golang, using [gin-gonic](https://gin-gonic.com/) framework.

I only ever want to support `application/json` as a mime-type and it would be great if it always be in UTF-8. The business logic of the service might break if it will get values in different encodings.

Is it a good idea to write a custom middleware that checks if `Content-Type` header has value `"application/json; charset=utf-8"` and returns some 4xx status in case it is not?

UPDATE:
Just found out that [ctx.ContentType()](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.ContentType) doesn't return `charset` part of the header. Is there a way to get it?

Comment: Yes it is good.

Comment: Hi! For the sake of future visitors, could you perhaps change the reference you're using, since (currently) it's a redirect to something behind a password-protected website at Ohio University? Are you directly pointing to the source code itself? If so, perhaps you were looking for something like https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/d4a64265f21993368c90602c18e778bf04ef36db/context.go#L817 ? Or maybe a link to some documentation page? Anyway, whichever might be the case, I believe that it would best to get a link that anyone can use _and_ possibly copy the paragraph explaining `ContentType()`.

Comment: Thanks for raising! the link is up to date now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing prevents you from simply looking at the `"Content-Type"` http header directly, to the tune of `ctx.Request.Header.Get("Content-Type")`.

The helper `ContentType` method is provided by `gin-gonic` especially for the rather common case of querying the "unadulterated" mime type of incoming data without too much hassle.

Comment: Could you also add an answer to the main part of the question, so that I could accept the answer?

Comment: I don't know what your application is about. In general, it seems you're talking about standard "Accept-Charset"/406 mechanism, which you can read about elsewhere.

Comment: Not exactly. [Accept-Charset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/headers/Accept-Charset) tells what charset does the client expect to get in the response. I'd rather validate that client sends everything as charset=utf-8 in request.